# How to add custom post type archive to menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been searching for weeks and I still haven't found a proper solution to this problem.

I am writing a Wordpress Theme. I have a custom post type called Works. I would like to add my Works archive to my menu and have it as well as it's posts highlighted when I access them.

I can access my archive and posts on the following links

Works archive: `/works/`

Works single post: `/works/postname/`

My solution so fare have been to name my `archive-works.php` template file with a template name (Work archive). Then create an empty page using that template and adding the page to the menu. This highlights the archive in the menu but not the single posts.

I can easily solve this with a custom link and some javascript but there must be a better and cleaner way.

Answer (score 16):

You can do a simple trick in your functions.php:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'current_type_nav_class', 10, 2);
function current_type_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    // Get post_type for this post
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

    // Go to Menus and add a menu class named: {custom-post-type}-menu-item
    // This adds a 'current_page_parent' class to the parent menu item
    if( in_array( $post_type.'-menu-item', $classes ) )
        array_push($classes, 'current_page_parent');

    return $classes;
}
```

In your case, you just have to add a class **'works-menu-item'** with that archive menu item by the admin panel;

Comment: Thanks that did the trick but I still wonder why this isn't easier to implement.

Comment: thank you! easiest solution from all I have googled up so far. Used it and works!

Comment: Can you please add an image on how to add the menu class, because in my case where CPT is `services`, I made `archive-services.php` and added a custom link menu with `http://localhost/project/services` and added a menu class `services-menu-item`, but it doesn't make any sense, and isn't working, I'm afraid. :(

Comment: Logged in to vote up! :) Easy extendable for hierarchical taxonomies approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

To add "custom posttype archive link" to menu, please look at the following guide

- Open file **functions.php** , and enter code below

  ```
  add_action('admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'wpclean_add_metabox_menu_posttype_archive');

  function wpclean_add_metabox_menu_posttype_archive() {
  add_meta_box('wpclean-metabox-nav-menu-posttype', __('Custom Post Type Archives'), 'wpclean_metabox_menu_posttype_archive', 'nav-menus', 'side', 'default');
  }

  function wpclean_metabox_menu_posttype_archive() {
  $post_types = get_post_types(array('show_in_nav_menus' => true, 'has_archive' => true), 'object');

  if ($post_types) :
      $items = array();
      $loop_index = 999999;

      foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
          $item = new stdClass();
          $loop_index++;

          $item->object_id = $loop_index;
          $item->db_id = 0;
          $item->object = 'post_type_' . $post_type->query_var;
          $item->menu_item_parent = 0;
          $item->type = 'custom';
          $item->title = $post_type->labels->name;
          $item->url = get_post_type_archive_link($post_type->query_var);
          $item->target = '';
          $item->attr_title = '';
          $item->classes = array();
          $item->xfn = '';

          $items[] = $item;
      }

      $walker = new Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist(array());

      echo '<div id="posttype-archive" class="posttypediv">';
      echo '<div id="tabs-panel-posttype-archive" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-active">';
      echo '<ul id="posttype-archive-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">';
      echo walk_nav_menu_tree(array_map('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $items), 0, (object) array('walker' => $walker));
      echo '</ul>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';

      echo '<p class="button-controls">';
      echo '<span class="add-to-menu">';
      echo '<input type="submit"' . disabled(1, 0) . ' class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu right" value="' . __('Add to Menu') . '" name="add-posttype-archive-menu-item" id="submit-posttype-archive" />';
      echo '<span class="spinner"></span>';
      echo '</span>';
      echo '</p>';

  endif;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 9):

### Thanks

Thanks to **rasmussvanejensen** for her/his nice question and **thethangtran** for the answer, I am still confused why Wordpress has not yet added such a good feature to its code base by default.

By the way I think there is even a better solution than the one provided by **thethangtran**, as it may break on some situations.

### Note 1

According to the Codex, using register_post_type, one can add extra `post_type`s to the installation. There is chance, some one need to [change the 'query_var'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#query_var) and thus the provided code will break.

### Note 2

In addition, it may not handle the `current-menu-item` class, which will be used for css customization to show the menu item as active.

### Note 3

As another note on the code, there is no need to define the `loop_index`, `item` and `items` variables. they are absolutely useless.

### A better solution

So I suggest using this alternative, for those who want a more robust solution to on this:

```
function prefix_add_metabox_menu_posttype_archive(){
  add_meta_box( 'prefix_metabox_menu_posttype_archive', __( 'Archives' ), 'prefix_metabox_menu_posttype_archive', 'nav-menus', 'side', 'default' );
}
add_action( 'admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'prefix_add_metabox_menu_posttype_archive' );

function prefix_metabox_menu_posttype_archive(){
  $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 'has_archive' => true ), 'object' );

  if( $post_types ){

    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ){

      $post_type->classes = array( $post_type->name );
      $post_type->type = $post_type->name;
      $post_type->object_id = $post_type->name;
      $post_type->title = $post_type->labels->name;
      $post_type->object = 'cpt_archive';

    }

    $walker = new Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist( array() );?>
    <div id="cpt-archive" class="posttypediv">
      <div id="tabs-panel-cpt-archive" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-active">
        <ul id="ctp-archive-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear"><?php
        echo walk_nav_menu_tree( array_map( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $post_types ), 0, (object) array( 'walker' => $walker ) );?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="button-controls">
      <span class="add-to-menu">
        <input type="submit"<?php disabled( $nav_menu_selected_id, 0 ); ?> class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Add to Menu' ); ?>" name="add-ctp-archive-menu-item" id="submit-cpt-archive" />
      </span>
    </p><?php

  }

}

function prefix_cpt_archive_menu_filter( $items, $menu, $args ){

  foreach( $items as &$item ){
    if( $item->object != 'cpt_archive' ) continue;
    $item->url = get_post_type_archive_link( $item->type );
    if( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == $item->type ){
      $item->classes []= 'current-menu-item';
      $item->current = true;
    }
  }
  return $items;

}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'prefix_cpt_archive_menu_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: It's appreciable work. Can it be more filtered for taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Appearance > Menus;

Make sure you have the Works' custom post type selected at Screen Options;

Click on the name of your custom post type to expand it and then click on the ‘View all’ tab;

You will see an option for All Works. Check the box next to it and then click on the Add to Menu button;

Your custom post type archive will now appear as a menu item in the right column;

By default, the label will be "All Works". You can change this by writing something different at the Navigation Label;

Click on the Save Menu button to save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on GitHub and it works out of the box by simply adding it to the `functions.php` without any walkers or extra classes.

> This code solves it by comparing the slug of the current post type
> with the navigation items, and adds a class accordingly.

[Code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/gerbenvandijk/5253921)