# CSS on active menu item in wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I've used custom CSS to create a strike-through effect for active menu items on my wordpress site: http://www.sekoul.com/

This is the code that I use to do this:

```
/* active menu item color */
.et_color_scheme_orange #top-menu li.current-menu-item > a {
color: #4a4a4a !important;
text-decoration: line-through !important;
}
```

However, on certain pages (ones which are generated by WP plugins), this effect doesn't work: http://www.sekoul.com/reading-list/

When I inspect the code, I can see that the ID's are not the same on these pages, but I can't seem to figure out which ID/class to apply the effect to. Any idea why this is happening / what I can do to select the appropriate ID/class ?

Comment: It's happening because for some reason the `.current-menu-item` class is only getting added to the `li` on the about page and not the other pages.

Comment: Any idea what I can to add it to the pages where it's missing? Or, alternatively, how I can select the active menu items where it isn't added?

Comment: The About and Contact pages have the `.current-menu-item` class added, but the rest aren't. The only difference I see between the pages are that the About and Contact pages have `menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page` class, while the others have `menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom`. As for a fix, you'll need to either use php or jquery to add that class on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing the `.current-menu-item` class because you're using a custom link. I'm assuming that "BOOKS" is a custom post type archive page, right?

If you need to have an active state on a custom post type archive page, you could try this solution that worked great for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602901/4303385

It'll add a metabox on the `Appearance > menu` with custom posts type archive page with active state support.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much! for anyone else reading this, I actually found a similar solution that worked well here: https://gist.github.com/gerbenvandijk/5253921