# How to add wordpress post archives years in menu?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this kinda a menu

[image]

press is my page. which i am gonna use as a WordPress post. so I have menu call press as you can see that. and in that menu, I want to submenu as a WordPress post archive years wise. I don't know how to do it.

i find similar question [How to add custom post type archive to menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879401/how-to-add-custom-post-type-archive-to-menu) but i don't know how to do it.

**in short i want to year of a specific post_type are added into menu press item dynamically.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i get the question but you can basically get the archives by year of a specific post_type with `wp_get_archives`

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

This should output a similar structure to the one in your image.

**Note: Will edit this answer if OP gives more clarifications.**

Comment: yes year of a specific post_type with wp_get_archives give the list of year but how to add dynamically into press menu item.?